# Are bit flags using ints in C/C++ actually safe?

Tags: c++, c

I've noticed that many C/C++ programmers implement sets of flags using something like the following:

```
#define FLAG_1 (1 << 0)
#define FLAG_2 (1 << 1)
#define FLAG_3 (1 << 2)

unsigned int my_flags = 0; /* no flag set */
my_flags |= FLAG_2; /* set flag 2 */
```

But is this approach actually sound?  It seems to me like it's making assumptions about the binary representation of unsigned ints that isn't part of the C/C++ language standard.  For example, that "0" is actually 0x0000.

Am I wrong?  Or am I right in theory, but not in practice given currently standard hardware?

Comment: If you couldn't do what you suggest, what *would* you do?

Comment: I would make those expressions `(1u << 0)` to ensure that they are _unsigned_ ints from the get-go, but that won't have any practical difference.

Comment: *"that '0' is actually 0x0000."*  That's like saying that 5 is actually 101 in binary.  They are two different representations of the same number.  One is not "actually the other" -- they are the *same thing.*

Comment: Are there any actual implementations of C or C++ on non-binary computers?

Comment: @dan04: it wouldn't matter. Binary is still binary - irrespective of how the computer stores it. Your average modern cell in a NAND flash chip holds more than just a 0 or 1 - have you ever noticed it? no.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: I know: old topic, but still: I encountered the exact issue where I was forced to specify `1u`. Consider `int` beeing 32bit and `size_t` beeing 64bit. The statement `size_t val = (1 << 31)` will have more than one bit set as it is a negative number which wraps around in the conversion to an unsigned number. This wouldn't matter if the types are of same size, but still, this occurs on production machines.

Answer (score 20):

### C++

The important part of the C++11 standard is §3.9.1/7 (*ISO/IEC 14882:2011(E)*):

> The representations of integral types shall define values by use of a pure binary numeration system.

This is clarified in a footnote:

> 49) A positional representation for integers that uses the binary digits 0 and 1, in which the values represented by successive bits are additive, begin with 1, and are multiplied by successive integral power of 2, except perhaps for the bit with the highest position. (Adapted from the American National Dictionary for Information Processing Systems.)

The results of shift operators are defined mathematically. For example, for `E1 << E2`:

> If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup> , reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. Otherwise, if E1 has a signed type and non-negative value, and E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

The bitwise operators are specifically defined as being bitwise. For example, for bitwise OR:

> The usual arithmetic conversions are performed; the result is the bitwise exclusive OR function of the operands.

Of course, under the as-if rule, the representation does not truly have to be the pure binary numeration system. The compiler must only produce a program that acts *as if* it were.

### C

In C99 (*ISO/IEC 9899:TC3*), pure binary notation is only guaranteed for bit-fields and objects of type `unsigned char` (§6.2.6.1/3):

> Values stored in unsigned bit-fields and objects of type unsigned char shall be represented using a pure binary notation.

Again clarified in a footnote:

> A positional representation for integers that uses the binary digits 0 and 1, in which the values represented by successive bits are additive, begin with 1, and are multiplied by successive integral powers of 2, except perhaps the bit with the highest position. (Adapted from the American National Dictionary for Information Processing Systems.)

The standard specifically points out that bitwise operations depend on the internal representation (§6.5/4):

> Some operators (the unary operator ~, and the binary operators <<, >>, &, ^, and |,
>   collectively described as *bitwise operators*) are required to have operands that have
>   integer type. These operators yield values that depend on the internal representations of
>   integers, and have implementation-defined and undefined aspects for signed types.

Comment: Yep, the as-if rule requires binary behavior to be preserved regardless of the actual implementation.

Comment: It seems like it says "have implementation-defined and undefined aspects _for signed types_", as if they're not undefined or implementation-defined for unsigned types, no?

Comment: Yeah, that statement is strangely worded. I couldn't find any clarification though. It's written as though depending on the internal representation isn't already introducing such aspects.

Answer (score 13):

While it's theoretically possible to run C or C++ on an architecture that uses non-power-of-2 arithmetic, the `|`, `&`, and `^` operators are defined to have bitwise behavior, so such a machine would need to emulate binary arithmetic.

It's therefore completely safe and portable.

Answer (score 7):

The current C and C++ standards both limit unsigned integer representations to a pure binary representation, so what you have above is entirely safe and guaranteed to work.

Comment: The observable behavior is that of a binary representation.  I don't think there's anything that requires them to actually be implemented that way, as long as the observable behavior is correct.

Comment: Except there is no need to define the flags as bitshifts, rather he should define them as base10 representations of the numbers :/ It looks a bit cleaner.

Comment: @ardentsonata it's much easier to define them as bit shifts and there's no disadvantage.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Don't you think having flags defined as `#define NEED_MOAR 131072` is just so much clearer than `1 << 17`? ;)

Comment: @BenVoigt: A good enough imitation can get by under the as-if rule, but even in the C89 standard says (§6.1.2.5): "The representations of integral types shall define values by use of a pure binary numeration system." with footnote 18 further clarifying: "A positional representation for integers that uses the binary digits 0 and 1, in which the values represented by successive bits are additive, beign with 1, and are multiplied by successive integral powers of 2, except perhaps the bit with the highest position."

Comment: As far as defining flags goes, I usually use hexadecimal, and find it fairly adequate as a rule.

Comment: @DanielFischer No, because `1<<17` is clearly setting a particular bit whereas it's easy to screw up a decimal number and get the wrong one. For example I had to check to see if 131072 was even a power of 2. Hexidecimal is better than decimal for this, but explicit shifts are the simplest and least easy to mess up.

Comment: @bames53 I think you missed something there ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer Apparently. Facetiousness doesn't come across well in this medium and I find it entirely believable that someone actually holds the position you feigned.

Comment: @bames53 I had the `;)` in there to remove all doubt, unfortunately it's too easily overlooked.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yep, I missed it.

Answer (score 2):

Bit shifting to the right always decreases the value of the integer, whereas bit shifting to the left will always increase the value.  This is irrespective of the endianness of the machine, so to answer your question: "Yes, this is sound because bit shifting works the same no matter the endianness of the system"

Does that answer your question?

Comment: @ardentsonata: Shifting to the right can't overflow. (But the question doesn't shift to the right, so I don't know why this answer focuses on that)

Comment: @BenVoigt If you shift right enough, it will overflow back to 0 wouldn't it? Eventually you're going to run out of bits to represent the number, albeit this is a huge corner case.

Comment: @ardentsonata You are correct.  My mistake.  Overflow can occur with left-shifting.  I need to stop thinking in python ;)

Comment: @ardentsonata But that is not overflow. Overflow is if you shift a positive _signed_ integer `e` far enough left that `e * 2^distance` is not representable in the type.

Comment: @DanielFischer, overflow is defined in both directions,  while wikipedia is not the best resource, wiki defines it as "the condition that occurs when a calculation produces a result that is greater in magnitude than that which a given register or storage location can store or represent."

Comment: @ardentsonata: But right shifting will never overflow.  It never increases the magnitude of the operand, so the result can never exceed the range of the type.

Comment: @ardentsonata Yes, what Ben just said I was going to say too.

Comment: @DanielFischer and BenVoigt, SORRY. I JUST CONFUSED RIGHT AND LEFT. And now I feel like a terrible person for wasting your time. @_@

Comment: @ardentsonata No problem, we're all confused sometimes, caffeine usually helps.